# style label and checkbox when used together (Plunker attached)

Tags: html, css, checkbox

http://plnkr.co/edit/a5RpkuWJFMfnOgoKr7pm?p=preview

Please refer to the plunker link. As per this, I want my checkbox to be on extreme left side and value 'Data:' to be on extreme right side at all times. I mean, even if we maximize, it should always be on extreme ends and not somewhere in between.

If you also noticed, the checkbox and value 'Data:' are not in the same line. Checkbox is a bit on upper side and value 'Data:' is only the lower side. How can I align them in the same line ?

Here is the code:

```css
.main_div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.5.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
  <div class='main_div'>
    <div>
      <div class='rules'>
        <span>
          <input type="checkbox" />
          <label>Data:</label>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't you just add `float:right;` to the label CSS?

Comment: @APAD1 nop, cause imput won't float, so label will break the line before going floatting right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here :

```
input {
  float: left;
}

.floated-label {
  float: right;
}

.rules {
 overflow: hidden;
}

<div class='rules'>
  <input type="checkbox" />
  <label class="floated-label">Data:</label>
</div>
```

Comment: hi @aplhextwix- i cannot use float right... since there are other labels in the project too which get affected by float right. can i create a class or an id for label ?

Comment: Of course - just add a unique class to the label you want to be floated. Always use classes for styling elements, never use ids.

Comment: `.floated-label` should be

Comment: @DarrenSweeney - Thanks

Comment: no need to float both of them text-align:right + input float:left does it too ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus - Either way you're adding two positional properties. So what difference does it make? ;)

Comment: @aphextwix none visually (bootstraps handle the float wrapping effects), but gives choice and something to be aware of to beginners :)

Comment: @GCyrillus - This is true. But it's probably overkill to provide all possible ways to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @aphextwix i think text-align + floating the input requires 2 rules where you used 3 , not sure of what you mean by overkill ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106953/discussion-between-aphextwix-and-gcyrillus).

Answer (score 0):

flex can be used here.

```css
.main_div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 2px;
}
.rules span {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  }
/* reverse order ? label {
  order:-1;
  }
*/
input  {
  margin:auto 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.5.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
  <div class='main_div'>
    <div>
      <div class='rules'>
        <span>
          <input type="checkbox" />
          <label>Data:</label>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

or float + text-align

```css
.main_div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 30%;
  margin: 50px;
  padding: 2px;
}
.rules  {
  text-align:right;
  }

input  {
 float:left;
  }
```

```html
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.5.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
  <div class='main_div'>
    <div>
      <div class='rules'>
        <span>
          <input type="checkbox" />
          <label>Data:</label>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```